# How do I pass command line options into a Spring application with gradle

Tags: spring, gradle

The [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) say

> By default, SpringApplication converts any command line option arguments (that is, arguments starting with --, such as --server.port=9000) to a property and adds them to the Spring Environment.

When I try to pass this into gradle

`gradle clean build --rerun-tasks --server.port=9000`

it fails with:

`Unknown command-line option '--server.port'.`

How do I get gradle to accept normal command line option arguments?  And note that I'm running tests, not the Spring application itself.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#running-your-application-passing-arguments

Comment: Nope:  `Problem configuring task :build from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--args'`.  If I just try `gradle  --rerun-tasks --args='--servicenow.password=123'` I get the same error.

Comment: The `build` task builds your application. It doesn't run it. The task that runs it is `bootRun`.

Comment: I'm running tests, not the application itself.  I could do this with `gradle --rerun-tasks --args='--server.port=9000'` but that fails too.

Comment: Then you can't pass arguments. Use the TestProperties annotation in your code, or set system properties in the test task for example.

Comment: I can't believe that gradle has ruined this highly desirable feature of Spring.

Comment: Do you mean TestPropertySource?  That won't work because what I need to do is pass in credentials and we can't store them in anything that gets checked into github.

Comment: It hasn't. You're executing gradle. gradle itself is a program that takes command line arguments. It executes plenty of tasks, by delegating to other programs. Why would it pass command line arguments it receives to every other program it starts. How wouldn't it make every launched program fail because it doesn't expect this argument? And even then, you're not running any Spring application. You're executing unit tests.

Comment: You just need to customize the test task, read values from wherever you want (gradle properties, command line args, whatever), and pass these values as system properties or env variables to the test execution.

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution is ti wrap build gradle call into sh script. And you can put you any CMD variables into the build script.

Example:

myBuildScript.sh:

```
gradle clean buildTaskName $1
```

In build.gradle use you variable like MY_VARIABLE_NAME.

Execute script:

```
MY_VARIABLE_NAME=value ./myBuildScript.sh
```